# Adjust deeplink redirects to Appstore all the time when opened from Instagram

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

We have enabled Adjust universal deeplinks for our apps. We have done all the setup required for deeplink to work. Also our Adjust deeplink works fine when we open it from apps like 'Slack' or 'Notes'. But when we try to open same deeplink from Instagram, user is redirected to App store every time even when app is already installed.

I have got an article regarding Deeplinking on iOS from Instagram and I read there that it will not work until it's paid add. Does anyone have any clear idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

Instagram requires deeplink / universal link to have a path appended to it, or the user will be taken to the store even if the app is installed.

E.g. this link will take user to the store:
https://app.adjust.com/x00abc1?deeplink=adjust%3A%2F%2F
however this one will open the app (if installed)
https://app.adjust.com/x00abc1?deeplink=adjust%3A%2F%2Fyour_path

Interestingly, this path does not have to be valid, there just needs to be a path. I.e. if the client / partner only wants the deeplink to open the app, they can add any invalid path. This will lead to the deeplink opening the app, but being served a path it does not recognise, which leads to the app simply not opening said path, but the app will be open.

**Note**: Some special characters, like ? are not technically a path, and will therefore not provide the desired behaviour.

Comment: This was very helpful. Solved an issue for my app.